# What is the difference between transverse section and longitudinal section?

Tags: terminology, anatomy, dissection

Can anyone explain the difference between transverse and longitudinal section?

Or are they the same?

Comment: One passes through long axis of the body while other is perpendicular to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an animal with bilateral symmetry, a longitudinal section is parallel to the anterior-posterior axis (labelled central axis in the image below). Sections through or parallel to either the sagittal or coronal (also called frontal) plane are longitudinal. A transverse section is perpendicular to the anterior-posterior axis and is also called a cross section.

[image]

[image source](http://physiolgenomics.physiology.org/content/18/2/232)